# Preposition drop in classifier constructions

Tags: prepositions, syntactic-analysis

Not being a native speaker, I’m rather intrigued by the conditioning environment of the rule which allows one to drop the preposition ***of*** in English classifier constructions of the form (1) (like e.g. ***hands of the size of a kickdrum***), where **NP1** is the term being classified (***hands***), and **NP2** the term that specifies the value of the classifier (***a kickdrum***).

> (1)   **NP1 + of + Classifier + of + NP2**

The full form is (2a), which is accepted by pretty much everyone, much like (2b), where the first ***of*** has been dropped. Many speakers also accept and produce examples in which both prepositions are dropped (2c). I'm not sure whether anyone accepts (2d); if it is ungrammatical across dialects, then preposition drop is conditioned from left to right--you drop the first, then the second, and so on.

> (2a) John has **hands of the size of a kickdrum**
>
> (2b) John has **hands the size of a kickdrum**
>
> (2c) John has **hands the size a kickdrum**
>
> (2d) (?)John has **hands of the size a kickdrum**

There appears to be some variation concerning the morphology. Some prefer to attach a possessive clitic at the very end (3), and some don't; it probably isn't a free option in every case, but I'll set this aside.

> (3a) John has **balls the size a peanut(’s)**
>
> (3b) You’d have to have **balls the size an elephant(’s)/a watermelon(’s)/a Studebaker(’s)** to try that in Glasgow

I'm actually not sure what the attachment site of the clitic is supposed to be here. Surely it ain't (4a). It could either be (4b) or (4c), but the question eludes me.

> (4a) [Balls the size a peanut]'s
>
> (4b) Balls [the size a peanut]'s
>
> (4c) Balls the size [a peanut]'s

Is the classifier perhaps lexically restricted? Or are the examples in (5) of more or less comparable acceptability? Is (5d) OK, or does the classifier have to be necessarily definite?

> (5a) The dark lashes framed **eyes the color the sea**
>
> (5b) John had **a cookie the shape a small island** on his palm
>
> (5c) I envy folk with **legs the length the Liffey**
>
> (5d) I recently saw a **child a height an adult(’s)**

Comment: I hear the size **of X**, not **a X**. But "the size a peanuts" sounds like mishearing "the size  o' peanuts."

Comment: Of the examples, I find only 2b acceptable.

Comment: Where are these examples from? Some look like they were taken from other sources, but some you made up yourself? I agree with the previous comments, but there may be a reason for using alternatives in some contexts.

Comment: These are reduced relative clauses with predicate nouns. _Whiz_-deletion takes out the _that is/are/was/were_ that marks them as clauses, leaving only the noun behind: _hands (that are) the size/shape/color of squirrels_. Note that all the examples have plural subjects. If you changed them to singular, would articles blossom? BTW, forget about _of_; wrong construction.